# Is there some physical-universal constant that ties to frequency with which the investigator "reaches out"?

Tags: the-expanse-novels

In book 4 *Cibola Burn*, in the 'interludes' the protomolecule construct "reaches out" 113 times per second.

Is there some physical frequency multiple or fraction that corresponds? Is this 113 per second explained elsewhere?

As a sort of follow up, is it the "Miller construct" that is reaching out or is it just the protomolecule trying to phone home?

Comment: I'd have an explanation for 137, but 113, no.

Comment: The frequency hints that the protomolecule or its engineers operate more quickly than humans. Revelations in line with such a hint emerge in *Leviathan Falls*. Keep reading. :)

Comment: @Lexible thx. I've read all 9 books and also Memory's Legion... going thru a second time to catch things better.

Comment: @Spencer sooo... going to mention what you think a frequency of 137 'whatever' per second might relate to?

Comment: @BradV - Caesium-137, I'm guessing

Comment: @Valorum I'll wait to hear from Spencer. I thought the same thing for why might say Cesium. But I wonder why folks might think frequency would relate to isotope weight. Back when I was designing military communications equipment I worked on an aircraft based atomic clock system that used an ovenized rubidium standard for frequency basis. Didn't care one wit about atomic weight, only about stable oscillation frequency.

Comment: No, it's the [fine structure constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant) which is almost exactly 1/137.  It's  dimensionless and therefore universal, but on further reflection the 'per second" part is entirely human-centric. It could be made to work if the protomolecule civilization had a longer "second". But also this is just speculation with nothing from the series or books to base it on. I thought we'd all be amused by an offhand comment,  however.

Comment: @Spencer THX... you are right in mentioning that human units of time are completely arbitrary so, relatively meaningless.  I suspect that authors used some multiple of a stable atomic frequency which ended up being 113/sec. Or it might be the apartment number of an old girlfriend.